# Change font of UILabel with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel

Normally, you use:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

to make a label reduce the size of its font whenever it is no longer possible to increase the size of its frame.

Is there any way to make it try an alternate font, like a condensed version of the same font family before it reduces font size?

Comment: did my answer address your question?

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I needed a programmatic solution. In the end, I just changed the design so that this behavior is no longer required. I'm still interested in finding out how, but I haven't had time to figure out if your solution would work yet.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few good ways to handle this. In IB select your label:

**Method 1:**

[image]

If you click the **plus** button, you can add specific fonts for a given size class.

In code:

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection
{
    if(self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular && self.view.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular)
    {
        //iPad here
        myLbl.Font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heyo" size:10];
    }
}
```

The better way, in my opinion, is **Method 2:**

[image]

With this approach, you can either tell the font to shrink up to a certain size, or instead identify a scale factor. Toy with these values until you get the desired result. I also talk about this topic in this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-adaptive-design--cms-22888).

In code:

```
//Minimum font size
[myLbl setMinimumScaleFactor:MIN_FONT_SIZE/[UIFont labelFontSize]];

//Scale factor
[myLbl setMinimumScaleFactor:0.4];
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is a bit of a pain to do programmatically though. Maybe I should look to sizeToFit instead?

Comment: You could still assign a minimum font size so it would work like the now deprecated label.minimumFontSize. For instance, if you wanted 18 points to the minimum, you could do this: [myLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:18/[UIFont labelFontSize]]. Alternatively, you could just use setMinimumScaleFactor if you didn't want a minimum font size.

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work for me, but this did.
You also need to use the system font in IB

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabelEx : UILabel


@end

#import "UILabelEx.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation UILabelEx

- (void) traitCollectionDidChange: (UITraitCollection *) previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange: previousTraitCollection];

    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:APP_FONT size:self.font.pointSize];   
}
@end
```